# How to share a handler method between multiple Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am building an application using ASP.NET Razor pages.

I already implemented registration and login using .NET Identity. In my _Layout partial view, I check whether `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. If it's not true, hyperlinks to Register and Login pages are displayed.

Now, if `User.Identity.IsAuthentiated` is true I want to display a hyperlink for logout. However, this one does not require a separate Razor Page. I simply want to logout and redirect to Index. I thought about using a handler method such as:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogoutAsync()
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
```

Is it possible I make it accessible from every single Razor Page? Or is there any other way of resolving my problem?

Other things I thought about:

1. Implementing this as an extension method of PageModel. However, to me, this solution seems to be quite clumsy and cheaty. I would need to inject `SignInManager<>` into every single Razor Page by default and I feel like it's wrong.
2. Creating an MVC controller. A simple solution that's going to work. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to do it using plain Razor Pages.
3. Adding a model to the _Layout partial view. However, for me to have access to the `RedirectToPage` method the model needs to inherit from `PageModel`. In such a case I get errors. So if I'm not to inherit from `PageModel` I'd need to find another way of redirecting to another Razor page which makes this similar to point 2 but with extra steps and more clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

To share a handler method between multiple Razor pages, I think you can put this method in `_layout.cshtml.cs`, and other razor pages need to reference `_layout.cshtml`.

I found an article similar to your needs, you can refer to [it](https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-razor-pages-logout-behavior).